# How can I remesh this right?

Tags: modeling, remesh

I am watching a tutorial(7.24 min https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmmSAsn_mOk) where a simple mesh is ment to be remeshed for later sculpting...[image: mesh before remesh]

For some reason it turns out very strange. What can I do? In the turorial something similiar happens, but I don´t see what exactly is done about it.
[image: mesh mush]

Comment: it's not clear if your mesh has been damaged (it can happen in Sculpt mode) or if 2 objects or meshes are overlapping

Comment: I changed the meshes size so it wouldn´t overlap with the sculpt. Still the same problem.

Comment: are these holes? if so, this may be a remesh bug

Answer (score 0):

The *Voxel* remesher has sometimes this problem and creates a mesh with a lot of holes, flipped faces, or missing parts when the original mesh is not manifold (watertight). It might be the missing thickness.

[image: non-manifold mesh]

The solution as shown in the video is to close the mesh and add a face at the top and bottom.

[image: manifold mesh]

Alternatively, you can try the *Remesh* modifier with one of the first three options: *Blocks*, *Smooth*, *Sharp*. Apply the modifier to use the mesh in *Sculpt* mode.

[image: remesh modifier]

Comment: Yeah, adding faces on top and nottom to close it works, thanks!